# How can i pass data into my fragments to my view?

Tags: java, android

hello im new to android studio
I just created my fragments and want to create  a button that randomizes a number. it worked before i did the fragments and now i simply doesnt know how to get in the same code i used before but..  it doesnt seem to find the id of my text view or my button

```
package com.example.thesapplikation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Random myRandom = new Random();

        Button buttonGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
        final TextView textGenerateNumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(myRandom.nextInt(100)));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you navigating between fragments? Also, make sure your button and textview exists in your layout `R.layout.fragment_home`

Comment: yeh i navigate between fragments i used this example for creating the bottom menu the code i have for the xml is the another fragment view and not home . so my button and textview are in a fragment called fragment_random.xml. but i dont think im refering to ti somewhere and i dont know what will happen if i change the return inflater above to that fragment. the code findViewById is red and not the argument(id) it seems to find the id inside

Comment: In a `Fragment`, you do not set up your `View`s in `onCreate()`. Move everything after the `super.onCreate()` call to `onViewCreated()`, and call `findViewById()` on the `View` passed into that method; e.g., `public void onViewCreated(View view, ...) { ... Button buttonGenerate = view.findViewById(R.id.generate); ... }`. Also, if that `Button` and `TextView` are in `fragment_random`, that's what you want to inflate in `onCreateView()`, not `fragment_home`.

Comment: You are missing your `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

It's same answer as @Mike said. Fragment's life cycle methods are different then that of an Activity, you can get more info from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

`OnCreate` is called before the `OnCreateView` so you dont have access to the fragment's view inside the `OnCreate` method. Move everything you doing inside `OnViewCreated`.
So your fragment code will be

```java
public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Button buttonGenerate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.generate);
        final TextView textGenerateNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

        final Random myRandom = new Random();
        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(myRandom.nextInt(100)));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for help when i try this my app just crash when i press the random fragment in the menu tab the other tabs works that only got text

Comment: Can you provide the logcat?

Comment: the red messsages?

Comment: yes exactly, you can copy and paste in online paste bean

Comment: it was to long to put it here so i edited my original post and added it below my code i first posted

Comment: did you see it? i get no errors from the code you posted only when i press that fragment in the emulator

Comment: It's saying that button is null, double check the layout `fragment_home.xml` has a button with id `generate`

Comment: this is where i dont understand this fragment thing i dont have my button in fragment_home.xml i have my button and text View in the fragment_random.xml if i put my button in my home wont it be visible in the home and not my random view?

Comment: Then change the ` return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)` to  ` return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_random,container,false)` in onCreateView of RandomFragment

Comment: ok thanks alot man i thought i had to use Home in every fragment and that they were somhow loaded into same view it works now fine when i changed it :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inside onCreateView(). Here, what it should look like to work.

```
public class RandomFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Random myRandom = new Random();

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        Button buttonGenerate =  root.findViewById(R.id.generate);
        final TextView textGenerateNumber = root.findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);

        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(myRandom.nextInt(100)));
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

}
```

I hope this works, works for me BTW. Best of luck! ☺️

Comment: hello thanks for help when i try this my app just crash when i press the random fragment